# AngularJS : Adding attribute to directive element inside ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive that works fine when used in isolation, but when it is used inside an ng-repeat it quits working.  I know that ng-repeat creates it's own isolate scope, but that shouldn't matter since I'm not trying to do anything outside of the isolate scope of my directive.  I've created a plunker to demonstrate the problem which you can see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4ADmznnDCZvuxJrcZQ0?p=preview.

In the compile function of the directive I am adding an ng-click attribute to the element. Notice that the "This works" link (which is not in an ng-repeat) works fine but the other links (which are inside ng-repeat) do not work.

Here is the directive from the plunker:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{
    name: 'John',
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: 'anonymous'
  }];
});
app.directive("myDir", function($compile) {
  return {
    controller: 'directiveController',
    compile: function(el) {
      el.removeAttr('my-dir');
      el.attr('ng-click', 'fxn()');
      var fn = $compile(el);
      return function(scope){
        fn(scope);
      };
    }
  };
})
.controller("directiveController", function($scope) {
    $scope.fxn = function() {
      alert('It works');
    };
});
```

And here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.12"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
        <a my-dir>This works</a>
        <a my-dir ng-repeat="id in [1,2]"><br>This does not work</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with binding the event in the link function instead of adding another attribute that has to be compiled ([**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PjiBcRpQGcswsQuNqds5?p=preview)):

```
app.directive("myDir", function($compile) {
  return {
    controller: 'directiveController',
    compile: function(el) {
      el.removeAttr('my-dir');

      var fn = $compile(el);
      return function(scope, el){
        el.bind('click', scope.fxn);
        fn(scope);
      };
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Thanks, @marcel-gwerder, that does work, however, it has one problem that keeps this from working for me.  I had over-simplified my Plunker for the sake of the question.  What I really need is to call a function on a parent controller.  So, while this does work and I can get it to call the parent method (by passing it in on the isolate scope), I can't figure out how to pass an argument.  Here is an updated Plunker showing the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/uRGkoh4qrYQhDxi2OlP8?p=preview.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me why you need all that directive stuff instead of just doing: `<a ng-click="click(user)" ng-repeat="user in users"><br>{{user.name}}</a>` ?

Comment: This is part of a larger application that I have simplified for the purpose of this question.  I have a form directive which has a form-page directive which has a multiple form-row directive and those have multiple form-column directives.  When a user clicks on a form-column, I need to notify the outer form and pass that column to a method in the form's controller.